# button is getting hide only double click of the label not in single click. i want it in single click

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, angularjs

I am hiding a button in Jquery function which is called at data-ng-click of a label in html page. but the button is getting hide only double click of the label not in single click. i want it in single click.

```
<label id="LabelApplications" class="Applications" style="" data-ng-click="GetBuildServerConfigData(this)">application name</label>

$scope.GetBuildServerConfigData = function (SelectedItem) {
            $('#button2').hide();
            $("#savebutton").hide();
    }
```

Comment: You need to add more code in order to get an answer. Post your `GetBuildServerConfigData` method in here.

Comment: We have no idea what `GetBuildServerConfigData(this)` is doing...

Comment: Also, ideally you shouldn't be mixing jQuery DOM manipulation with AngularJS. If you _have_ to use jQuery, there's an alternative with Angular's built in jQLite, i.e. `angular.element`

Comment: Added an answer below to address your issue

Comment: @dustin that is right. i used ng-hide with model. it worked. thank you

Answer (score 0, accepted):

While your question does not mention anything about the `GetBuildServerConfigData` function, if it is just the hiding that you need to accomplish you can do that like so:

```
 <label id="LabelApplications" ng-init="showButton = true" class="Applications" style="" data-ng-click="GetBuildServerConfigData()" ng-show="showButton">application name</label>
```

And in your controller:

```
//Controller code
$scope.GetBuildServerConfigData = function() {
  //ajax call (presumably)
  //.then(function(response) {
 $scope.showButton = false;
  //});
}
```

If this is all that needs to be done, you don't even need the `this` variable passed to the function, like you would do in jQuery

**Note:** Also, ideally you shouldn't be mixing jQuery DOM manipulation with AngularJS. Do it the Angular way :)

Working snippet below:

```js
var app = angular.module("testApp", []);
app.controller("testCtrl", function($scope) {
  $scope.GetBuildServerConfigData = function() {
    $scope.showButton = false;
  }
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/angularjs/1.2.23/angular.min.js"></script>
<div ng-app="testApp" ng-controller="testCtrl">
  <label id="LabelApplications" ng-init="showButton = true" class="Applications" style="" data-ng-click="GetBuildServerConfigData()" ng-show="showButton">application name</label>
</div>
```

Comment: with your answer . i got a idea to use ng-hide. it worked. thank you

Comment: If my answer helped, please upvote and mark as the correct answer :)